# Signature of nondegenerate symmetric bilinear form on $V\cong \mathbb{R}|^n$ is well defined

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, symmetric-matrices

If $\eta$ is some nondegenerate, symmetric bilinear on $V\cong \mathbb{R}^n$, I'm trying to show that the signature is the same regardless of a choice of orthonormal basis (is that the correct term for it in this case?), and hence well defined.

An outline of my proof goes as follows:

In some basis, I can write $\eta$ as a symmetric matrix satisfying:

$$\eta(v,w)=v^T\eta w$$

Since $\eta$ is symmetric, I can diagonalize $\eta$ it's eigenbasis, $\{f_i\}$,
and then, since $\eta$ is nondegenerate, scale each $f_i$ such that this new basis is orthonormal, and $\eta$ can be written as:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
-I_t&0\\
0&I_s
\end{pmatrix}$$
where $I_t$ and $I_s$ are the identity matrices of size $i\times i$ and $s\times s$ respectively, and $s+t=n$. Let $P=span\{f_{t+1},\dots, f_{t+s}\}$, this subspace is then positive definite, and of dimension $s$. Let $W$ be any negative definite subspace of $V$, then $W\cap P=\{0\}$, as for any $v\in V$, if $v\in W\cap P$, we have that $\eta(v,v)>0$,
and $\eta(v,v)<0$. This then implies that $\dim W+s\leq n$, so $\dim W\leq t$.

Now suppose that $\{b_i\}$ is any other basis which diagonalizes $\eta$ into the matrix:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
-I_{t+1}&0\\
0&I_{s-1}
\end{pmatrix}$$
Then $W=span\{b_1,\dots,b_{t+1}\}$ is a negative definite subspace of dimension $t+1$, which is a contradiction. So for any orthonormal basis, we see that $\eta$ must be, up to reordering:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
-I_{t}&0\\
0&I_{s}
\end{pmatrix}$$
so the signature of $\eta$, $(t,s)$ is well defined

Does that make sense? I feel kind of iffy about the middle part of the proof, where I'm trying to show that $\dim W\leq t$. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're proof of $\dim W \leq t$ looks good. But: "Now suppose that $\{bi_\}$ is any other basis which diagonalizes $η$ into the matrix..." Here, you set up a contradiction to something you just proved, namely that $\dim W \leq t$; you already showed that $t$ can't be any larger than it is, so this step does nothing. What you *have not* done is argue why $t$ can't be smaller. But this is easy: use the same argument as before to show that *positive-definite* $W$ has $\dim W \leq s$. Then since $s + t = n$, neither can vary.

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff I see what you are saying regarding how showing the same thing for a positive definite $W$ implies the claim, but how is this not equivalent? If I have such a basis $\{ b_i\}$, then the signature of $\eta$ in this basis is $(t+1,s-1)$, which would imply the signature isn't well defined, so that's a contradiction and the signature has to stay the same no? Am I missing something?

Comment: How does your argument show that $(t-1, s+1)$ is impossible?

Comment: You showed $\dim W \leq t$, so $t$ cannot get any larger. Then you said "assume that $t$ could be made larger; this is a contradiction, so $t$ cannot be made larger". All this does is again say that $\dim W \leq t$.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you. My apologies for the confusion

Comment: No need for apology! I'm glad I could help.